Can't get sticky row and column at the same time due to overflow-x
I have a table that is supposed to scroll both vertically and horizontally but with two twists. The header/footer must be fixed to the top/bottom and the left set of columns must be fixed to the left edge.
I used display:sticky, which worked as expected until I activated overflow-x:scroll on the right side of the table. Apparently, those two styles collide and produce an undesired result. It's been resolved by wrapping the inner markup in a section that is scrollable vertically. Unfortunately, that eliminates the horizontal scroll restricted to the right set of columns. Now, the entire table scrolls horizontally (including the left side columns supposed to be fixed).
Here's a fiddle illustrating the "unfortunately" resolved issue.
How can I approach it the best way?
In order to resolve the last, unfortunate part, a colleague suggest to put a copy of the left side columns on top of my table and let the entire original content scroll horizontally behind it, creating the illusion of sticky content.
This, however, introduces the issue of the header/footer of the overlay not being sticky on vertical scroll and we're back to square 0. In the fiddle, it can be shown by changing the style display to flex instead of none and the component is ID'ed fixy.
#fixy {
  display: none;
  border-color: fuchsia;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

#fixy .cell {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

An image of the desired perfect state. The left arrow points to the current horizontal scroll's caret. The right arrow points to the desired width/placement of the entire scroll.
HTML
<div class="section">

  <div id="fixy" class="table left">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="cell wide">left head 1</div>
      <div class="cell wide">left head 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell wide">val1a</div>
      <div class="cell wide">val1b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell wide">val2a</div>
      <div class="cell wide">val2b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell wide">val3a</div>
      <div class="cell wide">val3b</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="cell wide">left foot 1</div>
      <div class="cell wide">left foot 2</div>
    </div>

</div>
  
  <div class="table left">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="cell wide">left head 1</div>
      <div class="cell wide">left head 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell wide">val1a</div>
      <div class="cell wide">val1b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell wide">val2a</div>
      <div class="cell wide">val2b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell wide">val3a</div>
      <div class="cell wide">val3b</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="cell wide">left foot 1</div>
      <div class="cell wide">left foot 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table right">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="cell fixed">right head 1</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right head 2</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right head 3</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right head 4</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right head 5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell fixed">cont1</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont2</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont3</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont4</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell fixed">cont1</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont2</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont3</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont4</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell fixed">cont1</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont2</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont3</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont4</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">cont5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="cell fixed">right foot 1</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right foot 2</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right foot 3</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right foot 4</div>
      <div class="cell fixed">right foot 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
* {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

div.section {
  border-color: pink;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;

  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

#fixy {
  display: none;
  border-color: fuchsia;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

#fixy .cell {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;

  border-color: blue;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 0;

}

div.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;

  border-color: green;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

div.header {
  border-color: orange;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 90px;
  max-height: 90px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

div.row {
  border-color: pink;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
}

div.footer {
  border-color: purple;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 90px;
  max-height: 90px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.cell {
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.wide {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background-color: azure;
}

div.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}



From your question I think what you want is something like freeze in Excel
Try adding this style
* {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

div.section {
  border-color: pink;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;

  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

#fixy {
  display: none;
  border-color: fuchsia;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

#fixy .cell {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;

  border-color: blue;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 0;

}

div.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;

  border-color: green;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

div.header {
  border-color: orange;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 90px;
  max-height: 90px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

div.row {
  border-color: pink;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
}

div.footer {
  border-color: purple;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 90px;
  max-height: 90px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.cell {
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.wide {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background-color: azure;
}

div.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.table.left
{
  position: sticky;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:10
}



all I did is to add this to your style
.table.left
{
  position: sticky;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:10
}

Check : https://jsfiddle.net/p1Lr0fb9/
.section {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* for Internet Explorer, Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* for Firefox */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.section::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; /* for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

.right,.row
{
   cursor:all-scroll;
}

Added CSS to hide scrollbar and added cursor scroll indicator.

@ArunP Interesting. When I try your fiddle, there's no scroll nor caret at all. The scrolling works when I swipe my fingers over the pad but the visual indication is all gone. Do you see that on your machine? I've tested on FireFox, Edge and Chrome on a PC.

I have fully hidden the scroll bars and added an indicator to the cursor. Partial hiding isn't possible, but if you want an indication for scrolling, its possible to implement a custom scroll bar for that.

Got it. Enjoy your bountyrooni, mate. Awesome help. My teammate and I really appreciate it.
